# Let $f_n\in\mathcal C(0,1)$, $f_n\xrightarrow{\mathrm{unif}}f$ on every compact $K\subseteq(0,1)$. Is $f$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

This is part of a question on an old preliminary exam in Analysis at my institution. I think my answer is sufficient but I am not confident about it, and would appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $f$ need not be uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$.

Let $f_n=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}n+1&\text{if }x<\frac1{n+1}\\\frac1x &\text{if }x\geq \frac1{n+1}\end{array}\right.$. Then $f_n\xrightarrow{\text{unif} }f$ on every compact subset of $(0,1)$ where $f(x)=\frac1x$. But $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$.

Comment: You should explain why $f_n\to f$ uniformly on compacts. Other than that you're ok.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Maybe for that, the following would suffice: for any compact $K$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac1{N+1}<\min\{x:x\in K\}$, and thus $f_n=f$ on $K$ for all $n\geq N$.